# Add CSS class if div children height > 69

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a CSS class to a classes children 'a' (link) elements.
I have used console.log and it is definitely in the correct place as it runs each time the continue button is pressed.

```
if ($('.optionBox').children().height > 69){
        $('.opt').addClass('optionBoxmultiline');
    }else{
        console.log('not box is not above 69px');
    }
```

or - including the a in the children() tag

```
if ($('.optionBox').children(a).height > 69){
        $('.opt').addClass('optionBoxmultiline');
    }else{
        console.log('not box is not above 69px');
    }
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)!

Comment: `.children(a)` will give an error in the console - what error(s) do you have? This could be `.children("a")`.  Also `.height` is a function so at the minimum you'd want `.height()` but then, from https://api.jquery.com/height/ *"Get the current computed height for **the first element** in the set of matched elements"* - so you'd have to loop them all and add them up.

Comment: Hard to tell your use-case, but you might consider css `overflow:auto`

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear - I have a quiz. some options are multiple lines, so if one option is multiple lines, I want all the buttons to be the same size.

Comment: Ah, so are you saying: add a class to all if *any* are over specific height?